# Given two transcendental numbers, is their difference algebraic?

Tags: number-theory, transcendental-numbers

It is straightforward that a transcendental plus an algebraic is transcendental. I wonder if, given two transcendentals x and y we may find such algebraic a that x+a=y?

Comment: How about $x=\pi$ and $y=\pi+1$?

Comment: How about $x = e$ and $y = 2e$?

Comment: It depends on the two numbers. In principle, the difference of two transcendental numbers may be anything.

Comment: Hmm. If you are *given* $x$ and $y$, then of course $a=y-x$. This could be anything, depending on $x$ and $y$. For example, take $x=\pi$ and $y=1+\pi$. Or take $x=e$ and $y=e^2+e$.

Comment: I think we still don't know anything about $\pi-e$...

Answer (score 2):

You answered yourself: if $x+a=y$, then $x,y$ are a pair of transcendentals that differ by an algebraic.

This is of course not the case for any pair $x,y$, because there are many more transcendentals (uncountable) than there are algebraics (countable).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see the following:

Each transcendental belongs to a countable set of transcendentals which differ from itself and from each other by an algebraic number.

Since these sets of transcendentals are countable, and a countable collection of countable sets is countable, there must be an uncountable number of such sets to include all the transcendentals.